# How convert W3C Date XML to NSDate iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xml, nsdate

Problem:
I parse XML contain date 2011-03-28T22:13:06.000+09:00
I using NSDateFormatter with parten YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD in http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime
 But it not working

How convert this string to Date in IOS?

Thank you

Comment: I have added some code hope it helps to you..

Comment: Read the spec: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns.  The format should be "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ".

Answer (score 2):

```
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
NSLocale* en_US_POSIX = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[formatter setLocale:en_US_POSIX];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"];
NSDate* date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

The two locale lines are usually omitted but are necessary to cover an odd configuration case on iPhone.  Add appropriate releases if not using ARC.